# How to override default expiration time with Azure Event Grid publishing to queue?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-eventgrid

I created Event Grid subscription on Azure Blob Storage that sends message to Azure Queue every time a blob is created/modified. The message is inserted with default TTL, which is 7 days. Is there a way to change this parameter? I'd like to extend the expiration time to at least 14 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way from the AEG subscription to change any property of the message sent to the event handler resource.

However, as a workaround for that, can be used the *EventGridTrigger* function with a *CloudQueue* output binding to the storage queue.

The following code snippet is an example of the EventGridTrigger function for your solution:

run.csx:

```cs
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"

using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public static async Task Run(JObject eventGridEvent, CloudQueue outputQueue, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation(eventGridEvent.ToString());

    await outputQueue.AddMessageAsync(new CloudQueueMessage(eventGridEvent.ToString()), 
       TimeSpan.FromDays(14),    // TTL
       TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0), 
       new QueueRequestOptions(),
       new OperationContext());      
}
```

function.json:

```json
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "eventGridTrigger",
      "name": "eventGridEvent",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "name": "outputQueue",
      "type": "queue",
      "direction": "out",
      "queueName": "test",
      "connection": "myaccount_STORAGE"
    }
  ]
}
```