# Azure EventGrid queue programmatically set messages to never expire

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid

Does anyone know the best way (if any), to set message retention to never expire for EventGrid Subscriptions and queues? This is against blob store, triggered when files are added/updated/deleted. By default the retention is 7 days. I've been reading microsoft docs such as this  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/queues/storage-python-how-to-use-queue-storage?tabs=python which states "default time-to-live is seven days", but then doesn't expand on how to programatically change this. I can see from the SDK how to do it on a per message basis, but this doesn't help me as I want to do it at a Event Subscription level, not every time a message is created. I've attached a screen grab of how you can set it at Event Subscription level in the Portal

[Azure Portal Event Subscription Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rsQE.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to override default expiration time with Azure Event Grid publishing to queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65308953/how-to-override-default-expiration-time-with-azure-event-grid-publishing-to-queu)

Comment: Sort of, thank you, seems to take the ease of auto message generation away though. So whenever a file is created/updated/deleted, and force you to go through a function. This is fine for myself but a harder sell to my clients wanting an easy out of the box solution

Answer (score 1):

When you create the subscription for the handler to be a storage queue, you can configure TTL.

Here is a reference to the custom delivery property: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/delivery-properties#configure-time-to-live-on-outgoing-events-to-azure-storage-queues

CLI reference (see --delivery-attribute-mapping): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/eventgrid/event-subscription?view=azure-cli-latest#az_eventgrid_event_subscription_create

Comment: This shows you how to do it via the portal against the subscription, but I want to do it programatically. None of the SDKs or CLI seem to have the functionality, it is only against messages I can find it(timeToLive): https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/dotnet/Azure.Storage.Queues/12.7.0-beta.2/api/Azure.Storage.Queues/Azure.Storage.Queues.QueueClient.html

Comment: Added CLI reference to answer. :)

Comment: Thank you, I can see the property --qttl which is what I need. This is a great help, would prefer a Python or C# solution but this is enough to work with for now, and not have to manually update the subscriptions in the portal!